# Jquery .click and .mouseover not working on css3 display:table ,row, cell worked on html table?

Tags: jquery, css, mouseevent, mouseover, css-tables

I had a table that was generated out of standard html and used the JQuery `.mouseover` event listener as well as the `.click` listener. Everything was working fine.  I have since moved to gathering data from the Facebook API and then creating the information on the page using divs and CSS. The breakdown of the code is as follows:

These are the jQuery functions:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 

        $('.fbLikeImage').mouseover(function() {
              $likeID = this.id;

              document.getElementById('uiFBULikeName').innerHTML = this.alt; 
              document.getElementById('uiFBLikeImage').innerHTML = "<img width='70' height='70' class='fbUserImage' src="+ this.src +" >";

                });

        $('.fbLikeImage').click(function(){
            showDiv('uiCommentTextInputWrapper');
            showDiv('likeButtonWrapper');

            });


});
```

Then here is the rendered html:

```
<div class="table">
    <div class="tableRow">
        <div class="tableCell"> 
          <img width="50" height="50" id="192563358702" class="fbLikeImage"               src="http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-snc4/50352_192563358702_7313174_s.jpg" title="hi,     friend" alt="hi, friend">
        </div>
        <div class="tableCell"> 
           <img width="50" height="50" id="126279274071407" class="fbLikeImage" src="http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-snc4/195799_126279274071407_7781147_s.jpg"  title="Momentographics | Photography &amp; Design" alt="Momentographics | Photography &amp; Design">
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

There are many more rows than but this but this is the basic structure.

Here is the code from my CSS:

```
.table{
display:table;
}

.tableRow{
display:table-row;

}
.tableCell{
display:table-cell;
vertical-align:top;

}
```

This was working fine before I converted it to CSS based table layout. Any ideas wold be great I have not been able to solve this one.

Comment: This works for me in jsfiddle. The code you supplied is missing the 'uiFBULikeName' and 'uiFBLikeImage' elements and the 'showDiv' function. So I get errors when it reaches those lines. http://jsfiddle.net/NZsYK/

Answer (score 0):

```
    $(function () { 

        $('.fbLikeImage').mouseover(function() {
              var likeID = $(this).id;

              $('#uiFBULikeName').html($(this).alt); 
              $('#uiFBLikeImage').html("<img width='70' height='70' class='fbUserImage' src=' + $(this).src + ' >")

         });

        $('.fbLikeImage').click(function(){
            $('div uiCommentTextInputWrapper').show();
            $('div likeButtonWrapper').show();

            });
});
I would suggest something like this, but I'm not sure if the click function works like this.. else try by passing the class or ID with it.
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  The css DIV table had not been created and ready before the doc.ready function executed the listeners.  I put the listeners in another function and call them at the end of the function that creates the css table. This way the listeners dont fire before the other code is generated.